# Unable to display RTSP stream using gst-play-1.0, gst-launch-1.0

Tags: ubuntu, video-streaming, rtsp, nvidia, gstreamer

I have to display an RTSP stream using the gst-play-1.0 / gst-launch-1.0 commands on an NVIDIA Jetson-AGX device.

These are the commands I have tried:

**1. gst-play-1.0**

```
$ gst-play-1.0 rtsp://192.168.1.xxx:8554/main.264
```

in which case the terminal remains stuck at:

```
Press 'k' to see a list of keyboard shortcuts.
Now playing rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.xxx:554
Pipeline is live.
Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 261 
NVMEDIA: Reading vendor.tegra.display-size : status: 6 
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 261 
Prerolled.
```

**2. gst-launch-1.0**

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.xxx:8554/main.264 latency=0 buffer-mode=auto ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080 ! autovideosink
```

in which case the terminal remains stuck at:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://admin:mirage377@192.168.1.164:554
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
```

After pressing Ctrl+C:

```
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
Execution ended after 0:00:02.188911578
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

The URLs are of the following formats:

```
rtsp://192.168.1.xxx:8554/main.264
rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.xxx:554
```

The commands work on an x86 PC with Ubuntu 20.04 and Gstreamer 1.16.3. So, the RTSP feeds themselves are fine.

But, the commands don't work on the Jetson device.

**NVIDIA Jetson-AGX device info:**

L4T 32.6.1 [ JetPack 4.6 ]

Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Kernel Version: 4.9.253-tegra

GStreamer 1.14.5

CUDA 10.2.300

CUDA Architecture: NONE

OpenCV version: 4.1.1

OpenCV Cuda: NO

CUDNN: 8.2.1.32

TensorRT: 8.0.1.6

Vision Works: 1.6.0.501

VPI: 1.1.12

Vulcan: 1.2.70

Thank you for your patience and help.

Regards. :)

**Edit:**

Output from `gst-discoverer-1.0 rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.xxx:554`

```
Analyzing rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.xxx:554
Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 261 
NVMEDIA: Reading vendor.tegra.display-size : status: 6 
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 261 
Done discovering rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.xxx:554

Topology:
  unknown: application/x-rtp
    video: H.264 (Main Profile)

Properties:
  Duration: 99:99:99.999999999
  Seekable: no
  Live: yes
  Tags: 
      video codec: H.264 (Main Profile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also posted the query on NVIDIA's official forum([answer](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/gst-play-1-0-gst-launch-1-0-unable-to-display-rtsp-stream-on-xavier-agx/276025/3?u=forfuseuse)) as well as consulted some other people.

It seems that these two commands should work:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.xxx:554 latency=500 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM)' ! nv3dsink sync=0

$ gst-launch-1.0 -v uridecodebin uri=rtsp://username:password@192.168.1.xxx:554 ! nvvidconv ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink
```

Basically, it is recommended to use NVIDIA specific GStreamer plugins(prefixed by nv) on Jetson devices.

Regards.